# wordpress shortcode just displays its name as it

Tags: wordpress

```
<?php
    function ash_now_big(){
        $debut = 0; //The first article to be displayed
        query_posts('cat=45&showposts=1');
        while(have_posts()) : the_post();//while loop
            $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&offset=$debut');
            if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): 
                $output .= $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
                $output .=' <a href="'. the_permalink().'"><img src="'. $image[0] .'" style="width:100%"></a>';
          endif; // end of if
      endwhile; //end of while
 return $output;
}   
add_shortcode("ash_now_big", "ash_now_big");//creating shortcode
```

This shortcode when used just displays [ash_now_big] what could be the problem

Answer (score 1):

Where have you put this code in your project? Do you have any plugin or do you just want to put it in function file?

Please put below code in your theme functions.php file:

```
function ash_now_big(){
        $debut = 0; //The first article to be displayed
        query_posts('cat=1&showposts=1');
        while(have_posts()) : the_post();//while loop
            $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&offset=$debut');
            if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): 
                $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
                $output .=' <a href="'. get_the_permalink().'"><img src="'. $image[0] .'" style="width:100%"></a>';
            endif; // end of if
        endwhile; //end of while
    return $output;
}   
add_shortcode("ash_now_big", "ash_now_big");//creating shortcode
```

Comment: no plugin. i have just used it in my theme's function.php only .

Comment: No i tried did not work..I also tried doing this                                               if ( shortcode_exists( 'ash_now_big' ) ) {     echo "true"; } else {echo "false";}     but it shows false

Comment: can you please put echo and exit on function so we can identify its function is working or not ?

Comment: Thank you for your response.. The issue wa snot in this function. i just removed the function which i created before doing this, and magically it started working :-)